# SQL Show all items that are on hire before and up until a certain date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a number of tools an on-hire date and an off-hire date.

I want to show all tools that are on hire in a given month.

eg.

```
tool      on_hire    off_hire
tool 1    02/01/2016 15/01/2016
tool 2    16/12/2015 16/01/2016
tool 3    05/01/2016 20/02/2016
```

I have a variable `set @startdate = 20160101` and `@enddate = 20160131`

It is possible to get everything that started in JAN with a WHERE but I need to capture tool 2 also which started in DEC but ended in JAN

Any ideas?

Help is much appreciated, cheers

Comment: Well, you actually need a query which returns everything that ended in january 2016, the start doesn't matter, right? It's not clear why you make an exception for tool 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Takes me back, but this is what you want to show EVERYTHING on hire in the period, including non-returned items

```
select *
from MyTable
where on_hire < @EndDate
and (off_hire >= @StartDate or off_hire is null)
```

For the follow up, total number of days for each tool

```
with CTE as
(
    select *
    from MyTable
    where on_hire < @EndDate
    and (off_hire >= @StartDate or off_hire is null)
)
select Tool,
       sum(datediff(dd,
                    case
                      when off_hire > @EndDate then @EndDate
                      when off_hire is null then @EndDate
                      else off_hire
                    end,
                    case
                      when on_hire < @StartDate then @StartDate
                      else on_hire
                    end)) as DaysOnHire
from CTE
froup by Tool
```

Comment: I'm also looking to calculate the number of days it was on hire in the JAN period only if you know how to do that :-) I may create another question for this if I can't work it out, cheers

Comment: I ended up using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720914/count-number-of-days-on-hire-in-jan

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
WHERE on_hire BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate 
OR off_hire BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
```

Comment: Why is this correct? OP hasn't mentioned it. Why not simply `WHERE off_hire <= @enddate `

Comment: What happens if an item goes on hire before the start date and is returned after the end date? This won't show the item at all

Comment: He need every possibility record in between startdate AND enddate  @TimSchmelter

Comment: @ShakeerMirza: those columns describe a timespan(time when a customer hired a tool and when he will give it back). OP wants all tools which were  brought back january2016, so `WHERE off_hire <= @enddate` (no need to filter start).

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
create table #yourtable (tools varchar(50),on_hire datetime,off_hire datetime)

insert into #yourtable

select 'tool1'  ,'2016-01-02'  ,'2016-01-15' 
union all
select 'tool2'  ,  '2015-12-16' ,'2016-01-16'
union all
select 'tool3' ,   '2016-01-05', '2016-02-20'

select * from #yourtable
where datepart(mm,on_hire)='01' and tools<>'tool2'
union all
select * from #yourtable
where datepart(mm,on_hire)='12' and datepart(mm,off_hire)='01' and tools='tool2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Two lines `x1-x2` and `y1-y2`(date ranges etc) intersect when:

```
x1 <= y2 and y1 <= x2
```

So:

```
select * from table
where on_hire <= @enddate and @startdate <= off_hire
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be three options:

```
1.     |______| --hire time
    s|—————|e

2.     |______| --hire time
           s|—————|e

3.     |______|--hire time
    s|—————————————|e


4.     |______|--hire time
        s|———|e    --included in 2 and 3
```

```
    DECLARE @startdate date = '01/01/2016', @enddate DATE = '01/31/2016'
    ;WITH tb(tool,on_hire,off_hire)AS(
        SELECT 'tool 1','01/02/2016','01/15/2016'  UNION                            
        SELECT 'tool 2','12/16/2015','01/16/2016'  UNION    
        SELECT 'tool 3','01/05/2016','02/20/2016'
    )
    SELECT * FROM tb
    WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(d,tb.on_hire,@startdate)>0 AND DATEDIFF(d,@startdate,tb.off_hire)>0
    OR DATEDIFF(d,tb.on_hire,@enddate)>0 AND DATEDIFF(d,@enddate,tb.off_hire)>0
    OR DATEDIFF(d,tb.on_hire,@startdate)>0 AND DATEDIFF(d,tb.off_hire,@enddate)>0
```

Comment: This is vastly over complicated for the scenarios described

Comment: When you analyse overlaps by cases, you'll tend to come up with complex conditionals. In fact, to determine whether two periods (such as here, a report period and a hire period) overlap, you need only determine that period 1 starts before period 2 ends and that period 2 starts before period 1 ends. After that, the only fiddliness is whether two periods which exactly abut (end date of one equals start date of the other) should be considered to be overlapping. And that just affects whether you use `<` or `<=` in your comparisons.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Soooo, like wot I dun did?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I gree with you,thank you. In my project,I had created a function before