# Count number of days on_hire in JAN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In follow up to my previous question

[SQL Show all items that are on hire before and up until a certain date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715764/sql-show-all-items-that-are-on-hire-before-and-up-until-a-certain-date/41715867#41715867)

I'm now trying to count the days on on hire only in the set variable period.

I have worked out the number of days the tool is on rental using

```
   ,(CASE WHEN off_hire = '21121231'
         THEN datediff(DAY, on_hire, GETDATE())
         ELSE datediff(DAY, on_hire, offhire)+1
    END) AS 'DAYS_OF_RENTAL'
```

21121231 being the date it uses if the tool is still out.

I'm trying to work out the number of days it was on hire in JAN only using

```
   ,(CASE WHEN (on_hire > @startdate) AND off_hire > @end_date
         THEN datediff(DAY, @startdate, @enddate )
         ELSE datediff(DAY, on_hire, off_hire)+1
    END) AS 'CALC_DAYS_ON_HIRE'
```

This is obviously not working but this is the route I've been trying at the moment.

Example Data

```
tool      on_hire    off_hire
tool 1    02/01/2016 15/01/2016
tool 2    16/12/2015 16/01/2016
tool 3    05/01/2016 20/02/2016
```

I have a variable `set @startdate = 20160101` and `@enddate = 20160131`

Any help is greatly appreciated, I am still learning but getting there :-)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
declare @t table (id int, tool  varchar(10),    on_hire date,    off_hire date);
insert into @t values
(1,1,'2016-01-01','2016-01-10'),
(2,1,'2016-01-15','2016-01-20'),
(3,2,'2015-12-01','2016-01-10'),
(4,3,'2016-01-20','2016-02-10'),
(5,4,'2015-01-01','2017-01-10')


select tool,  sum(datediff(d,on_hire,off_hire)) + 1 dayshired
from
(
select tool,
        case 
            when on_hire < '2016-01-01' then '2016-01-01'
            else on_hire 
        end as on_hire,
        case 
            when off_hire > '2016-01-31' then '2016-01-31'
            else off_hire 
        end as off_hire         
from @t
) s
group by s.tool
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like this

```
   ,(CASE WHEN (on_hire < @startdate) AND off_hire > @enddate
         THEN datediff(DAY, @startdate, @enddate )+1

         WHEN (on_hire < @startdate) AND off_hire < @enddate
         THEN datediff(DAY, @startdate, off_hire)+1

         WHEN (on_hire > @startdate) AND off_hire > @enddate
         THEN datediff(DAY, on_hire, @enddate )

          WHEN (on_hire > @startdate) AND off_hire < @enddate
         THEN datediff(DAY, on_hire, off_hire )

    END) AS 'CALC_DAYS_ON_HIRE'
```